# Vectorizing a for-loop that merges two data frames by column

Tags: r, for-loop, merge, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1),ncol=10,nrow=1))
colnames(df1) <- LETTERS[seq(1,10)]
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,1),ncol=4,nrow=1))
colnames(df2) <- c("C","D","A","I")
```

Some of the column names in `df2` match column names in `df1` and `df1` always contains every possible column name that can occur in `df2`. I want to append `df1` with a new row which holds the value of df2 for matching columns and a 0 for non-matching columns. My current approach uses a `for-loop`:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df1)){
  if(colnames(df1)[i] %in% colnames(df2)){
    df1[2,i] <- df2[1,which(colnames(df2)==colnames(df1)[i])]
  } else {
    df1[2,i] <- 0
  }
}
```

Well, it works. But I wonder if there is a cleaner (and faster) solution for this task, perhaps taking advantage of vectorized operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res <-merge(df1,df2,all=T)[,colnames(df1)]
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res
#     A B C D E F G H I J
#   1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
#   2 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly more efficient would be `rbind_all` from "dplyr":

```
library(dplyr)
rbind_list(df1, df2)
#   A  B C D  E  F  G  H I  J
# 1 0  0 1 0  0  1  1  1 0  1
# 2 1 NA 1 1 NA NA NA NA 1 NA
```

Assign to "res" and replace `NA` with "0" in the same way identified by @akrun.

Comment: Probably the simplest in terms of key presses. Surprised to see you use `dplyr` though - turned to the dark side? ;-)

Comment: @thelatemail, I know. Wonders never cease. Still not a "dplyr" convert, but I have to learn to use it to be able to answer questions on SO, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just using assignment:

```
df1[2,] <- 0
df1[2,names(df2)] <- df2

#  A B C D E F G H I J
#1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
#2 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

...and just to prove it works with other values:

```
df2$C <- 8
df1[2,] <- 0
df1[2,names(df2)] <- df2

#  A B C D E F G H I J
#1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
#2 1 0 8 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
```